# Protobuf - can I skip a few field numbers?

Tags: protocol-buffers

can I do this? Skipping a few, so I can add those in the future? I do so to make sure some fields are always at the end.

```
message {
optional string field_1 = 1;
optional string field_2 = 2;

// skip some, so I can add them in the future;


// but I really want this one to be in the end;
oneof {
optional string details_xyz = 21;
optional string details_abc = 22;
} 



}
```

Comment: This is valid. In fact even the implementation itself uses other numbers for internal purposes. `Field numbers 19,000 to 19,999 are reserved for the Protocol Buffers implementation. The protocol buffer compiler will complain if you use one of these reserved field numbers in your message.`